# onmouseover does nothing in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have an event "onmouseover" which works fine on Chrome but does nothing on IE8 (I have to use IE8 in my company)
(the same with "onmouseout")

Here's my code :

```
function add() {
//Some kind of code uninteresting
    resultats+='<option onmouseover="return changeCouleur(this.id)"  onmouseout="return retourCouleur(this.id)" id="'+ttSuggest[i]+'" value="'+ttSuggest[i]+'">'+ttSuggest[i]+'</option>';
elem.innerHTML(resultats);

}

function changeCouleur(select_id)
{
    elem=document.getElementById(select_id);
    elem.style.color="red";
    return false;
}

function retourCouleur(select_id)
{
    elem=document.getElementById(select_id);
    elem.style.color="black";
    return false;
}
```

Is there a problem ? I have no errors and no warnings in the consol...

Comment: Take into consideration that the IE console does not work until you open it. That means that if an error occurs while the IE console is closed and then you open it, the error will not show. Try loading your page with the console opened and let us know if you can see something new.

Comment: Yes I know that, and there is no errors in the IE console.

Comment: If your purpose is just change some style, `:hover` works in IE8 already; But personally, I doubt that these kinds of style works on `<option>` in IE8.

Comment: No, it doesn't work on `<option>`that's why I use JS

Comment: @Geo You're not "using JS"; you're just using JS to change its style, which actually _IS_ CSS. `element.style.color="black";` is essentially `<option style="color:black">`, so if it doesn't work in CSS, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Passerby, it works. My code works on browser like CHROME, but, it doesn't on IE, I don't search any errors in my code, I search a way to make it work in IE, a kind of another syntax.

Comment: @Geo Yes I noticed that you say it work in Chrome, but Chrome is not IE **8**. And you don't see any error because there's no error, the code is not "wrong", it's just that IE8 doesn't support _some_ CSS for `<option>`, so it doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: Ok, this is the kind of answer I expected. If IE doesn't support this CSS, I'll try something else !

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to find the ID if its hovered in the same element. Try this:

```
function add() {
    //Some kind of code uninteresting
    resultats += '<option onmouseover="changeCouleur(this);" onmouseout="retourCouleur(this);" id="' + ttSuggest[i] + '" value="' + ttSuggest[i] + '">' + ttSuggest[i] + '</option>';
    elem.innerHTML(resultats);
}

function changeCouleur(el) {
    el.style.color="red";
}

function retourCouleur(el) {
    el.style.color="black";
}
```

Comment: If it does not work, then maybe the problem come from another. What with that `ttSuggest[i]` used for? Inside a loop?

Comment: `ttSuggest[i]`is an array of words used to create the `<option>` in the `<select>` so for each words in the array, it create an option. Do  you want the entire function ? (Remeber it works on Chrome I think it's a problem from IE ?)